# Caching an Android application data, is it safe to always use getFilesDir()?

Tags: android, caching

Is it safe to always use "getFilesDir()" as the only destination to cache your app's data?

1. Will that directory always be available?
2. What happens when the destination has no free space? does Android handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will that directory always be available?

Yes.

> What happens when the destination has no free space? does Android handle that?

Android has no ability to magically cause a device's on-board storage to increase in size. Android takes various steps to try to help the user clean up used storage space. However, eventually the user can still run out of space. Depending on how you are working with internal storage, you may get an `IOException`, or you may get a silent failure (e.g., write a zero-byte file).